# Running Clojure on Heroku and getting Error H14 (No Web Process running)

Tags: clojure, heroku

I've followed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1001206), [this blog post](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/06/13/deploying-a-clojure-web-app-on-heroku/) and downloaded and deployed [this example](https://github.com/thearthur/clojure-compojure-heroku-example) and in all 3 cases I get:

```
Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET etc-etc-999.herokuapp.com
```

Is there any usual clojure + heroku gotcha's that I might be falling foul of?

**Things I've tried/checked:**

- I've tried running my app locally and it works,
- I've made sure my local and remote copies are in sync,
- I've tried seting the heroku config PORT=8080 and tried un-setting it
- I've tried restarting the apps
- I've got a working Procfile
- I've checked that I have 1 web process up and running.
- and have made sure I'm set up to use the cedar stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the problem...

```
GET "/"
```

Works fine locally and is exactly how the above git project does it...

But I had to change this to:

```
GET "/*"
```

To get it to work on Heroku.